# Whats the best way to have RESTful URLs and still track pageview counts using analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, restful-url

#### What I Wanted

I was going to use urls like `/item/xxx` (viewing an item) and `/item/xxx/photo` (viewing the full screen photo of an item) because I thought that looked better and was more RESTful.

#### Problems

- I realized that I wouldn't be able to track total item views because the urls would cross over each other (i.e. you can see the total hits you had to all urls starting with `/item/` but that would include the photo URLs).
- I wouldn't be able to track the total photo views because the url would have the id before the photo part (i.e. I can't look at all urls starting with `/item/xxx/photo`

#### Question

Am I wrong? Can i still find these numbers (I'm using Google Analytics)? Or am I better off changing the URLs to `/item/view/xxx` and `/item/photo/xxx`? This is for an iPhone app so the URLs are really arbitrary (I can set them to whatever I want and no one will see them except in the analytics).

Comment: You can use report filters with regex and see those numbers. Notice that report filters are not the same as profile filters. Report Filters are non-destructive and can be applied to historical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get metrics for just URLs with the `/item/xxx` structure while excluding `/item/xxx/photo` ones, instead of just typing text into the filter box, you can use the advanced filter option for **'Matching RegExp'**. (Click on the text *'advanced'* next to the text entry field).

And use a regular expression to exclude the `/item/xxx/photo` while also including `/item/xxx`:

- Exclude Page Matching RegExp: ***`item/(.)*/photo$`***
- And Include Page Containing:    ***`item/`***